# ML estimate of sum of guassian variables?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

consider the sum $z=x_{1}+...+x_{k}$, where the scalar variables $x_{i}$ are statistically independent and Gaussian, each having the same mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2_{x}.$ 
how can I construct the maximum likelihood estimate for the number K of the terms in the sum. 
How can should I consider the pdf to find maximum likelihood estimation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $z$ will be normally distributed with mean zero and variance $K \sigma_x^2$. Then you proceed as one normally will find the MLE for the variance of a normal random variable. As you know $\sigma^2$ you can isolate $K$.

Comment: yes, z will be $N(0,K\sigma^{2})$, but in this stage, partial derivative which  element, how can I do this?